# Go - Perform unsigned shift operation

Tags: go, binary-operators

Is there anyway to perform an unsigned shift (namely, unsigned right shift) operation in Go? Something like this in Java

```
0xFF >>> 3
```

The only thing I could find on this matter is this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/2L7NfqtZYls/Ezf6TbFhlEEJ) but I'm not sure what I have to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> A numeric type represents sets of integer or floating-point values.
>   The predeclared architecture-independent numeric types include:
>
> ```
> uint8       the set of all unsigned  8-bit integers (0 to 255)
> uint16      the set of all unsigned 16-bit integers (0 to 65535)
> uint32      the set of all unsigned 32-bit integers (0 to 4294967295)
> uint64      the set of all unsigned 64-bit integers (0 to 18446744073709551615)
>
> int8        the set of all signed  8-bit integers (-128 to 127)
> int16       the set of all signed 16-bit integers (-32768 to 32767)
> int32       the set of all signed 32-bit integers (-2147483648 to 2147483647)
> int64       the set of all signed 64-bit integers (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)
>
> byte        alias for uint8
> rune        alias for int32
> ```
>
> The value of an n-bit integer is n bits wide and represented using
>   two's complement arithmetic.
>
> There is also a set of predeclared numeric types with
>   implementation-specific sizes:
>
> ```
> uint     either 32 or 64 bits
> int      same size as uint
> uintptr  an unsigned integer large enough to store the uninterpreted bits of a pointer value
> ```
>
> Conversions are required when different numeric types are mixed in an
>   expression or assignment.
>
> [Arithmetic operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators)
>
> ```
> <<   left shift             integer << unsigned integer
> >>   right shift            integer >> unsigned integer
> ```
>
> The shift operators shift the left operand by the shift count
>   specified by the right operand. They implement arithmetic shifts if
>   the left operand is a signed integer and logical shifts if it is an
>   unsigned integer. There is no upper limit on the shift count. Shifts
>   behave as if the left operand is shifted n times by 1 for a shift
>   count of n. As a result, x << 1 is the same as x*2 and x >> 1 is the
>   same as x/2 but truncated towards negative infinity.

In Go, it's an unsigned integer shift. Go has signed and unsigned integers.

It depends on what type the value `0xFF` is. Assume it's one of the unsigned integer types, for example, `uint`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    n := uint(0xFF)
    fmt.Printf("%X\n", n)
    n = n >> 3
    fmt.Printf("%X\n", n)
}
```

Output:

```
FF
1F
```

Assume it's one of the signed integer types, for example, `int`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    n := int(0xFF)
    fmt.Printf("%X\n", n)
    n = int(uint(n) >> 3)
    fmt.Printf("%X\n", n)
}
```

Output:

```
FF
1F
```